# Is it possible to generate a junit.xml test report file with Insomnia CLI just like Newman does?

Tags: junit, newman, insomnia

When using Postman, you can specify tests for each of the requests in your collection, then, when executing the collection in a CI/CD environment through Newman, you can specify a command line like this:

```
newman run my-collection.json -r cli,junit --reporter-junit-export junit.xml
```

This will generate a file named `junit.xml` containing the results for each test in your collection.

How can the same be achieved using Insomnia's CLI [Inso](https://insomnia.rest/products/inso)?